# Which folders to copy when copying Flutter app to a new project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app in which I edited `pubspec.yaml` file and all files on `/lib` folder.

If I create a new project in flutter, which files are necessary to copy from that project to have a copy of that app? Is it only **"those files that I edited"** or there are some files automatically being edited when I edit `pubspec.yaml` or any file from `/lib` folder which I should also copy them in order to my older app work in a new project properly?

Comment: Theoretically if you copy only the files you changed/added across all of the application, not just the ones in `/lib` and `pubspec.yaml`, but also anywhere else on project directory, as long as you run `flutter packages get` it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated files can be generated again, no worries. If you know for sure all the files you have edited, you can copy them. But if you change the package, you'd have to change the imports in the files as well. As João Soares said, you should also run flutter packages get to get all the packages you have on your pubspec.yaml